# Version mismatch in Nuget Package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

I was trying to create a gis application when i installed a nuget package, it showed the following error,

Error       **The 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime.WPF' nuget package cannot be used to target 'net6.0-windows'. Target 'net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0' or later instead.**

I have tried downgrading the version of the nuget package but it didn't work, it keeps giving out the same error, where can i download net 6.0 windows 10.0.18362.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to Project/YourProject Properties/
2. Make sure target framework is .NET 6
3. Change Target OS version to 10.0.18362.0
4. If you get an error like this: "The runtime pack for microsoft.windows.sdk.Net was not downloaded. Try running a nuget restore" just restart visual studio

Keep in mind that your project will only work for windows version 10.0.18362.0 and later using this method

Comment: Just to be more accurate, please note that specifying an OS version in the target framework only affects the API surface available at compile time, so it *may* still work in earlier OS versions.
For more info, please refer to:
[OS version in TFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#os-version-in-tfms)